# How to compare a window scroll with an array full of offset tops?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array that contains the offset().top of tags that have "ScrollJS" class name.

I have written the code below to check when window scrolls, if the windows.scrollTop is equal with one of the values in array, alert something, but It doesn't work.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var WindowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (TopPositions.indexOf(WindowScroll) > 0) {
        alert('Yep !');
    }
});
```

I'm sure & tested that my array contains some values when scrolls but no idea why it doesn't work.
Thansk for your helping !

Comment: value of `WindowScroll ` are you getting ?

Comment: @Mahi Yes, I console.log & showed me every WindowScroll.

Comment: check in console `TopPositions.indexOf(WindowScroll)`

Comment: I checked & showed "-1" 47 times.

Comment: it means you don't have data in array . try filling array first .

Comment: @Mahi I checked it again and I saw that when I close to my Box, It writes "0", So I made my code correct because I forgot that INDEXs start with "0", So for first value worked, But I have 2 values in Array, 0 => 100px that worked I mentioned top but for 1 => 300px doesn't work ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in  your code example it looks like your `TopPositions` variable is not filled or simple doesn't match the actual scroll position *exactly* it would also fail for the first element in the array as the `indexOf` would return `0`.

The better implementation (if compatible to the browsers you're using or translated by babel) would be to use `some`:

```
const topPositions = [0, 100, 200];
$(window).scroll(function () {
    const windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (topPositions.some((topPosition) => { return topPosition === windowScroll})) {
        alert('Yep !');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ebi ..., It accurancy is weak ? Because I should move slow to alert "Yep !".

Comment: The event doesn't get triggered for every pixel (as you probably figured by now). What you could do is to change the test so instead of `===` use a test if the value is near the other value or simply if it is bigger than the other value heavily depending on your use case.

Comment: Thanks My Friend ... :)